# how to track an webpage when it is redirected from another web page within a web view in android

Tags: android

I load "www.gmail.com"  in a webview,after login the a new webpage will be loaded i.e. our gmail account page.

I have to track that url when I submit login details and the new webpage is loading,I don't need any hard coded value to redirect to any webpage,I want to get that url when a webpage is loaded from another webpage,how can I achieve this.Please help me.

This is my code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    title_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.urltxt);
    showWeb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview_details_body);
    showWeb.setWebViewClient(new HelloWeb());
    showWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    showWeb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);//show the webpage in fullsize with all info
    showWeb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    WebSettings webSettings = showWeb.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    showWebClick();

}
private void showWebClick() {
            showWeb.loadUrl("http://www.gmail.com/");


}


public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode,KeyEvent event){
    if((keyCode==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)&&showWeb.canGoBack()){
        showWeb.goBack();
        return true;
    }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
public class HelloWeb extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView vw,String url){
        vw.loadUrl(url);
        s=vw.getUrl();
        title_text.setText( s);
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(vw, url);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using method getUrl() of webview client.

But, This is not always the same as the URL passed to WebViewClient.onPageStarted because although the load for that URL has begun, the current page may not have changed.

You can refer below link :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl%28%29

So you have to call geturl method on onPageFinished method. It will be good.

@Override
 public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

```
       /*do your stuff here.*/

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `webview` will most likely call either `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` or `onLoadResource` in its `webviewclient` with an url of its redirect.

If I understand your question correct, try overriding `onLoadResource` in your `WebViewClient` and look at the url parameter.

Using `onLoadResource` will also generate urls for other resources as well, such as images.